# jaxb: xjc.sh java.activation not found

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11, java-platform-module-system, openjdk-11

I've downloaded jaxb-ri:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── bin
├── docs
├── License.txt
├── mod
├── samples
└── ThirdPartyLicenseReadme.txt
```

My java version is:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
```

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to perform `xjc.sh -help`, I'm getting this error message:

```
Java major version: 11
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.activation not found, required by com.sun.istack.runtime
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:315)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveAndBind(ModuleDescriptor.java:2693)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(ModuleBootstrap.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders(ClassLoader.java:211)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.initialize(Thread.java:430)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:155)
```

Comment: Which version exactly did you download? By the package name I guess it's `2.*`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the javax.activation module. I did it by:

- Download jar: [javax.activation-1.2.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar) (or from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0))
- Copy it to the "mod" folder
- Add downloaded jar in the jsc.sh file under JAXB_PATH, like so:

```
    ...
    JAXB_PATH=${JAXB_HOME}/mod/jaxb-xjc.jar:\
    ${JAXB_HOME}/mod/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:\
    ${JAXB_HOME}/mod/jaxb-api.jar:\
    ...
```

Then run the xjc.sh again :)